# Синтаксический разбор (2)

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно разобрать по составу следующие предложения:

*Вот стол* (при указании на предмет).
*Вот они мы.*

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

***Вот стол.*** Повествовательное, невоскл., простое, односоставное, назывное (номинативно-указательное), неосл. Частица ***вот*** не является членом предложения.

***Вот они мы.*** — тоже назывное (номинативно-указательное). Частица ***вот они*** не является членом предложения.

**Указательные** предложения, кроме значения бытия, существования, содержат указание на имеющиеся предметы и явления. Структурным признаком таких предложений являются указательные частицы *вот (вот и), вон, а вот*. Семантическая специфика их заключается в указании на появление, обнаружение предмета. Пример: *Вот ива*.

В предложениях с частицей *вот* указательное значение может быть ослаблено и на первый план выдвинуто значение оценки (иронической, неодобрительной и т. д.), например, предложения с частицей *вот* могут обозначать внутреннюю несостоятельность называемого: *Думает это бедняга и слезами так и захлебывается. Вот они, заячьи-то мечты.* (С.-Щ.). Оценочно-бытийные предложения объединяют предложения субстантивного типа, в которых значение бытийности сопровождается оценкой. Структурной особенностью этих предложений являются эмоционально-экспрессивные частицы: *ну, то-то, тоже мне, а еще, да и, и же, что за, какой, ай да, прямо* и др. Желательно-бытийные предложения отличаются особой функцией — они передают желательность называемого. Структурным признаком их являются частицы *только, если, лишь* в сочетании с частицей *бы* (показателем ирреального наклонения). Например: *Только бы здоровье!*